# What are the steps required in moving an existing VS2013 website solution to cloud services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

We have developed and deployed several website solutions through Visual Studio.  Now, we would like to host these through Web Roles on Azure Cloud Services.

To now host a solution as a Web Role, is the process as simple as creating a new Windows Azure Cloud Service in Visual Studio, then importing all related projects into a new ASP.Net Web Role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - add an Azure Cloud Project to your solution and add the existing web project as a web role in the cloud project.  See [How to: Migrate and Publish a Web Application to Azure from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420322.aspx) for details.

Comment: BTW, this approach assumes you are using a "web app", not a "web site". A "web site" requires a few extra steps.

Comment: Concur, but the question specifically asks about Web Roles.

Comment: I wasn't referring to IaaS. Simply calling out that the instructions you liked to are specific to a Web App and that a Web Site (two different VS project templates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.120).aspx), requires a slightly more complex approach. See this link. While web apps are the more common (and recommended) approach these days, there are still some Web Site projects out there that are being migrated.